# Webview URL bar not completing URL

Tags: android, url, webview

i have a webview and a URL bar along with a progress bar but the problem is, i have to write full address of a website like "http://www.google.com/" to open it can this be solved by adding a prefix in the url? if yes then how?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private EditText urlEditText;
private ProgressBar progress;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());


    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);//Enable Cookies
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//Enable Java Script
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/"); //Set Home page
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);//Remove ScrollBars
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(12);//Set Font Size
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);//Enable Image Loading
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);//Enable Flash
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//Transparent Screen When Loading
  //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//Set Zoom Controls 

    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);//Set Cache (8mb)
    String appCachePath =     getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);//Set Cache (8mb)
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);//Set Cache (8mb)


 //////888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888   

    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);

    Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
            if (validateUrl(url)) {
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl(url);

                MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            }
        }

        private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {         
        MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);       

/////88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{


webview.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {

     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack())

    {
webView.goBack();
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: is it giving any errors ?

Comment: pass the cookie with url

Comment: in Every request r u authenticating the user??

Comment: @rup35h i dont know what do you mean by that

Comment: pass your cookie like this

additionalHttpHeaders.put("cookie",yourcookie);
webView.loadUrl(url, additionalHttpHeaders);

Comment: @rup35h i have no java experience, can you specify where to paste it ? and what to remove?

Answer (score 0):

I applied this logic...hope it helps you

```
if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://"))
 {
      url = "http://" + url;
 }
```

you can make similar changes ...i thought it will help you not to write whole url...sorry if i am wrong..but i did this and it had helped me once...

Comment: but what about the domain like ".com", ".co.in"?

Comment: It has  url.endsWith(suffix); function ...have a try with this...but i think you have to provide it explicitly..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (validateUrl(url)) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
}
```

Try this. It helped me:

#### UPDATED

```
if (validateUrl(url)) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    HashMap<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    additionalHttpHeaders.put("cookie", yourCookie);
    webView.loadUrl(url, additionalHttpHeaders);
    MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
}
```

Comment: url cannot be resolved, yourcookie cannot be resolved

Comment: idk what cookie are you talking about??

Comment: @apk page that you are trying to load in Webview before that are validating. Means only logged in user can access that page??

Comment: what do you mean by logged in? i just opened google that's all and its not opening without typing full address in the url field

Comment: then use above answer that will fit for you

Comment: read the question first, i already have it in my code exactly the same thing